# Jupyter notebook keeps getting frozen when trying to plot a bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly-python

I am trying to make a bar chart but my jupyter notebook is keeps getting frozen. My data set is not very large. It has around 421k rows.

I have no problem when I am trying to plot a histogram on this data. It's working perfectly fine. But when I am trying to make a bar chart, it's keeps getting frozen. Does anyone know why is this happening?

For reference, The data set look like this -

[image]

Matplotlib code for the bar chart -

```
plt.bar(train["Type"],train["Weekly_Sales"])
plt.show()
```

Also tried in plotly but it is also not working -

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=train["Type"],y = train["Weekly_Sales"]))
fig.show()
```

Working perfectly fine when plotting histogram.

```
plt.hist(train["Weekly_Sales"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? There are no data issues, it's looking perfectly fine.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to plot 421.000 bars side by side?

Comment: @Pascalco no, that's the total number of rows of data. I included it so that people don't assume that the dataset is way too big that jupyter can't handle it and the reason for the freeze. I just want to plot three bars on the x-axis related to the type of the store A, B, and C type and on the y-axis the weekly sales data. I have no problem in making a histogram but problem is arising when creating a bar plot.

Comment: Well, `plt.bar(train["Type"],train["Weekly_Sales"])` effectively wants to plot 421.000 bars. You could try seaborn's [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), which by default would plot bars with the mean together with error bars.  As default bootstrapping is used to calculate the confidence interval, this also could be slow. You could set `sns.barplot(x=train["Type"], y=train["Weekly_Sales"], ci="sd")` for errorbars with standard deviation (or `ci=None` to skip them completely).

Comment: @JohanC  ok, Now I understand that first I need to summarize the data like calculate the mean weekly sales by each store type and then plot the data. And barplot with seaborn works without transformation as you said. Thanks for the help.